# React Context API + hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am fairly new to Context API. So bassicaly,  I want when I press on the Button in the ButtonComponent everything in ButtonComponent disapears as well in ImageComponent but when I click on the Button  nothing happens. I am kind of stuck with this I would be very grateful if I got someone to  help me if possible. Thanks in Advance!

```
//HiddenContext
import React from "react";
export const HiddenContext = React.createContext(false);

function HiddenProvider({ children }) {
  const [hideButton, setHideButton] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setHideButton(true);
  }

  return (
    <HiddenContext.Provider value={{ hideButton, handleClick }}>
      {children}
    </HiddenContext.Provider>
  );
}


// App Component/Parent
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
export const HiddenContext = React.createContext(false);
function HiddenProvider({ children }) {
  const [hideButton, setHideButton] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setHideButton(true);
  }

  return (
    <HiddenContext.Provider value={{ hideButton, handleClick }}>
      {children}
    </HiddenContext.Provider>
  );
}

 function App() {
  const { hideButton } = React.useContext(HiddenContext);
  return (
    <HiddenProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <ImageComponent hideButton={hideButton} /> 
      </div>
    </HiddenProvider>
  );
}


//ButtonComponent
import React, {useState,ReactFragment} from 'react'
import { HiddenContext, } from './HiddenContext';
function ButtonComponent() {
  const { hideButton, handleClick } = React.useContext(HiddenContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!hideButton && (
        <li>
          <img className="image" src="./icons" alt="" />
          <Button
            onClick={handleClick}
            variant="outlined"
            className="button__rightpage"
          >
            Hide
          </Button>
          <caption className="text"> Hide</caption>
        </li>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// ImageComponent
import React, {useState, ReactFragment} from 'react'
import { HiddenContext, } from './HiddenContext';
const ImageComponent = () => {
  const { hideButton } = React.useContext(HiddenContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {!hideButton && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <img src="icons/icon.png" alt="" />
          <caption>Image </caption>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### We created here 2 context - instead of 1

I make a codesendbox for us to see the fix.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-night-i95fr

We should create context only one time, to wrap the App component with the provider, and we can use this context like you did wherever we want

And relative to the beginner, it seems from your code that you understand what you are doing

about your comment - attached a pic

[image]

Comment: Button Component is rendered elsewhere is in the SideBar which is rendered in App which I forgot to put in the Code. Anyway I remove context from App it asks me to import Hidden Provider I do it like this (import HiddenProvider from "./HiddenContext";) and then it gives me this error (Attempted import error: './HiddenContext' does not contain a default export (imported as 'HiddenProvider'

Comment: so you need to add default export like in the codesendbox

Comment: It is horrendous but stll nothing happens when I click on the button. Thanks man you tried I am gonna sleep now.

Comment: Yes maybe you'm tired, look at codesandbox tomorrow :)

Comment: It wokred until tommorow now i got error (  Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the context value outside the provider (in `App`).
Try to remove this from `App`, like so:

```
 function App() {
   return (
     <HiddenProvider>
       <div className="App">
           <ImageComponent  /> 
       </div>
     </HiddenProvider>
   );
}
```

Comment: I remove HiddenProvider from App it ask me to import the HiddenProvider.I import the Provider like this (import HiddenProvider from "./HiddenContext";) and then it gives me this error (Attempted import error: './HiddenContext' does not contain a default export (imported as 'HiddenProvider')